# Smooth transition between distorted and undistorted result of Movie Distortion node

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes

*I want my render to morph between two tracking scenes.* One is distorted, another not.

Distortion is quite obvious, so animating mix factor between original image and distorted doesn't make it look good. K1 and K2 parameters in tracking settings are not keyframeable.

Right now, I'm animating mix factor with lots of blur to mask transition, but is there any "tidy" option?

Comment: Could you add further detail *why* you want to do this? What effect are you looking for? Can you give us an example?`There may be a different/easier way than the distorsion node.

Comment: I want my render to morph between two tracking scenes.

Comment: Just dissolving from distorted to undistorted will not create any kind of dislplacement. You would need to do some form of point warping as you dissolve. The compositor in blender does not have any tools to do such thing. You might want to try using images as planes, adding some subdivisions and animating the vertices to create some form of distortion on the mapped images.